# To save data from multiple edittext fields into a csv file in Android

Tags: android, csv

I am very new to Programming and this is my very first question. I am designing an app for my Forest Department.

I have created a layout in xml file with more than 100 edittext fields.

[image]

Now when user clicks the SUBMIT button, I want to read this data and store it to csv file. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Reading the data? Storing? Opening a file?

Comment: From an EditText one gets the text with String text1 = editText1.getText().toString();. So not to difficult.

Comment: Reading and storing the data. I will be asking user to input 103 data in one go and then will ask him to submit. Now I want to store this data in an array as well as in a csv file.

Comment: Yes we knew already. You told that before. Althougj the array is new. Now what problems do you have? You are not elaborating although asked to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for parsing of CSV files natively so we have to rely on third party library. There is 3rd party library [Opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is very good library to read and write CSV file in android platform.
At first you need to download this library [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/files/opencsv/). Then, Implement the Submit button onClickListener like:

```
mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
        String baseDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = "Data.csv";
        String filePath = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
        File f = new File(filePath );
        CSVWriter writer;
        // File exist
        if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()){
            mFileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath , true);
            writer = new CSVWriter(mFileWriter);
        }
        else {
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
        }
        String[] data = getDataStringArray();

        writer.writeNext(data);

        writer.close();
    });
```

In `getDataStringArray()` get all data from your textViews and return as Array of String like this:

```
public String[] getDataStringArray(){
        String[] data = {mTV1.getText, mTV2.getText, ...};
        return data;
    }
```

In your mainifest add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```